# Change Firefox Developer Edition icon in dash?

Tags: firefox, icons

So I have installed Firefox Developer Edition and placed it in `/opt/firefox`. I also created a related `firefoxDeveloperEdition.desktop` in `/usr/share/applications` that I have altered the `Icon` property to specify the icon of my preference. This sets the icon in the system's application and system launcher as expected and desired. However, in the dash it remains the same. Additionally, when opening Firefox Developer Edition it asks me if I want to set it to be my default browser. Agreeing to this creates another `.desktop` file, only this time in `~/.local/share/applications`. This does not alter the icon in launcher / applications. Editing it there to change the `Icon` field does not update the dock. Of note, in `/opt/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default` there are a few icons e.g. `default-128.png` which appears like the icon in the dock. However, I can not find a configuration file to fix this. Please advise.

Comment: WM_Class of your developper edition is probably the same as that of your regular version.

Comment: What does that mean exactly @vanadium?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For running applications, the icon in the dock is differentiated according to the WM_CLASS property of the window. My guess is that your Firefox Developer Edition runs with the same window class as the regular Firefox, i.e. `"Navigator", "Firefox"`.

You need to start Firefox adopting a different WM_CLASS, and you need to tell the launcher to associate the icon with that WM_CLASS. Edit the `.desktop` launcher of Firefox Developer Edition to:

1 Start Firefox adopting a different window class, e.g.:

```
Exec=/opt/firefox_dev/firefox --class Firedev
```

2 Add the following desktop entry:

```
StartupWMClass=Firedev
```